# Color histogram of the picture in java - wrong results

Tags: java, histogram, bufferedimage

I wanted to create a color histogram of the image like described here(looked at the section Example): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram

I copied the picture of the cat from the wikipedia example section: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Odd-eyed_cat_by_ihasb33r.jpg and got different results.
I paste my code below. Did I make any mistake?

My code:

```
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[][][] ch = new int[4][4][4];
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("kot.jpg"));
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int alpha = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
                int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
                int blue = color & 0x000000ff;
                ch[red / 64][green / 64][blue / 64]++;
            }
        for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++)
                for(int p = 0; p < ch[i][j].length; p++)
                    System.out.println("t[" + i + "][" + j + "][" + p + "] = " + ch[i][j][p]);

    }
}
```

---

```
**Wikipedia results**:

Red Green   Blue    Pixel Count
0   0   0   7414
0   0   1   230
0   0   2   0
0   0   3   0
0   1   0   8
0   1   1   372
0   1   2   88
0   1   3   0
0   2   0   0
0   2   1   0
0   2   2   10
0   2   3   1
0   3   0   0
0   3   1   0
0   3   2   0
0   3   3   0
1   0   0   891
1   0   1   13
1   0   2   0
1   0   3   0
1   1   0   592
1   1   1   3462
1   1   2   355
1   1   3   0
1   2   0   0
1   2   1   101
1   2   2   882
1   2   3   16
1   3   0   0
1   3   1   0
1   3   2   0
1   3   3   0
2   0   0   1146
2   0   1   0
2   0   2   0
2   0   3   0
2   1   0   2552
2   1   1   9040
2   1   2   47
2   1   3   0
2   2   0   0
2   2   1   8808
2   2   2   53110
2   2   3   11053
2   3   0   0
2   3   1   0
2   3   2   170
2   3   3   17533
3   0   0   11
3   0   1   0
3   0   2   0
3   0   3   0
3   1   0   856
3   1   1   1376
3   1   2   0
3   1   3   0
3   2   0   0
3   2   1   3650
3   2   2   6260
3   2   3   109
3   3   0   0
3   3   1   0
3   3   2   3415
3   3   3   53929
```

---

**My results:**

```
t[0][0][0] = 28257
t[0][0][1] = 1181
t[0][0][2] = 0
t[0][0][3] = 0
t[0][1][0] = 58
t[0][1][1] = 1414
t[0][1][2] = 156
t[0][1][3] = 0
t[0][2][0] = 0
t[0][2][1] = 0
t[0][2][2] = 0
t[0][2][3] = 0
t[0][3][0] = 0
t[0][3][1] = 0
t[0][3][2] = 0
t[0][3][3] = 0
t[1][0][0] = 2898
t[1][0][1] = 36
t[1][0][2] = 0
t[1][0][3] = 0
t[1][1][0] = 1517
t[1][1][1] = 9858
t[1][1][2] = 1389
t[1][1][3] = 0
t[1][2][0] = 0
t[1][2][1] = 357
t[1][2][2] = 2405
t[1][2][3] = 1
t[1][3][0] = 0
t[1][3][1] = 0
t[1][3][2] = 0
t[1][3][3] = 0
t[2][0][0] = 2794
t[2][0][1] = 3
t[2][0][2] = 0
t[2][0][3] = 0
t[2][1][0] = 7533
t[2][1][1] = 33807
t[2][1][2] = 40
t[2][1][3] = 0
t[2][2][0] = 0
t[2][2][1] = 60782
t[2][2][2] = 371779
t[2][2][3] = 87464
t[2][3][0] = 0
t[2][3][1] = 0
t[2][3][2] = 438
t[2][3][3] = 60218
t[3][0][0] = 0
t[3][0][1] = 0
t[3][0][2] = 0
t[3][0][3] = 0
t[3][1][0] = 123
t[3][1][1] = 4056
t[3][1][2] = 0
t[3][1][3] = 0
t[3][2][0] = 0
t[3][2][1] = 9118
t[3][2][2] = 14215
t[3][2][3] = 118
t[3][3][0] = 0
t[3][3][1] = 0
t[3][3][2] = 12257
t[3][3][3] = 72160
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK , but the problem in the image which you use to test on it :

the **Wikipedia** Use [**this**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Odd-eyed_cat_by_ihasb33r-2.gif) image to test

and you use [**this one**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Odd-eyed_cat_by_ihasb33r.jpg)

Comment: Excuse me but I use this full color one. I updated code so now it just can be copied and ran.

Comment: Oh now I get it... the opposite you wrote : ) They use 8bit I use 32 bit. Thanks : ).

Comment: ah sorry i opposite the two link :)